# Writing to serial port in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, serial-port, expect

I need to communicate with a serial port inside a Perl script. I need to send characters and read the input and search for strings.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? By using "expect" or by opening the /dev/ttys0 device in Perl itself ? Or some other method ?

I prefer to use perl but I don't know if it is simple and featured as expect.

Comment: what have tried so far? show your code.

Comment: i did some experiments with expect plugin for perl but it seemed to clumsy. i intend to try the suggestion by "askovpen"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $port = new Device::SerialPort("/dev/ttyS0"); 
$port->user_msg(ON); 
$port->baudrate(9600); 
$port->parity("none"); 
$port->databits(8); 
$port->stopbits(1); 
$port->handshake("xoff"); 
$port->write_settings;

$port->lookclear; 
$port->write("some command to com-port");

my $answer = $port->lookfor;
# or my $answer=$port->read(255);
```

Comment: great thanks! in Linux, do i need root privileges to perform the above ?

Comment: @Strudle no. you need user/group, who can read/write /dev/ttyS0. ls -l /dev/ttyS0 to view

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Win32::SerialPort` for Win32 and `Device::SerialPort` for linux.

Answer (score 0):

- [IO::Termios](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aTermios)
- [Device::SerialPort](http://p3rl.org/Device%3a%3aSerialPort)